# My users are not logging out in Jmeter and only one user which has logged in at the end perform all the transaction

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I was trying to write a load testing script, I have created one as well but the users I am passing are all not performing the transactions, I have used correlation to capture the UUID of users and have passed this UUID in all of the samplers, now when we are logged in the last user that comes from the login only that iser execute the transactions for 'n' number of times. Please can anyone tell me why this is happening and what can be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear hence I can only provide a generic piece of advice:

1. Run your test with 2 virtual users and 2 iterations and inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, this way you will be able to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing and if not - identify where the problem is
2. Check that all correlated/parameterized variables have their anticipated values using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
3. Check that there are no any suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If after all you will still experience issues include comprehensive details into your question covering:

- JMeter configuration
- Expected behaviour (preferably with request/response details from the [network tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) of the real browser)
- Actual behaviour (preferably  with request/response details from the View Results Tree listener)